# use OnClick from different class android

Tags: java, android

this is probably simple but i am still a beginner
i have a button in class MainActivity and i want to use the onclick method in another class(another activity) i am aware that it could be easily achieved by making it public static and accessing it as instance but in my case i can not make it public static for some good reason

button xml:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/googledrivemain"
    android:layout_width="78dp"
    android:layout_height="77dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="149dp"
    android:background="@drawable/google"
    android:onClick="onClickOpenFile"
    android:paddingTop="6dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.51" />
```

MainActivity button:

```
 public void onClickCreateFile(View view) {

    fileOperation = true;

    // create new contents resource
    Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient)
            .setResultCallback(driveContentsCallback);

}
```

second class button:

```
btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
           use onclick from mainactivity...??
        }
    });
```

Comment: "for some good reason"... Tip: There is a reason, and `static` methods within Activity is never good. Also: Never ever make `new` Activity

Comment: What type of class is this "second class"? Please [edit] your question to add it

Comment: What does the other listener do?  If it uses things specific to that other activity then you should probably leave it alone.

Comment: What is the second class type ? is it a Activity, a Fragment , .. ?

Comment: it is another activity

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this

```
btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     ((MainActivity) getActivity()).onClickCreateFile(v);
    }
});
```

i think it will work.

Comment: thanks, but it says ca not resolve symbol 'get activity' . can you think of something else?

Comment: Hi @MIKEPERETZ if i may ask, what functionality do you want to acheive?

Comment: I just want to use the method which invoked when the button press (it is opening a google drive storage based on api client)

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap the code you invoke from the `MainActivity.onClickCreateFile()` into another class and call it from wherever you want

And never, NEVER, do something like `new MainActivity()`. Activities are managed by the system

Comment: You can't make that method static

Comment: I didn't say that. I said "wrap the code [...] into another class". I'll update the answer

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. According to the question, there is already "another class", why introduce another?

Comment: Or you can use @Jonathan Aste solution. Is basically the same I said. And why the downvote???

Comment: the second class is a different activity. the onclick method in main class contains objects that could not be static and also it is not possible to invoke the code from another class because the main class has api client for the activity session.

Comment: Wrapping everything that is needed is enough. And also a good practice. You should avoid "god classes" like Activities that do everything

Answer (score 0):

You can create a handler class, something like this:

```
public static class ClickHandler {

    private ClickHandler mInstance;


    public static ClickHandler getInstance(){
        if(mInstance == null){
            mInstance = new ClickHandler();
        }
        return mInstance; 
    }


    public void onClickCreateFile(View view) {

         fileOperation = true;

         // create new contents resource
         Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient)
        .setResultCallback(driveContentsCallback);

    }

}
```

Then wherever you need it:

```
btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ClickHandler.getInstance().onClickCreateFile(view);
    }
});
```

Comment: It might be cleaner to implement `OnClickListener` on `ClickHandler`

Comment: Yes, that's a matter of legibility. Anyway it would have the same performance.

Comment: Besides, he can use the method outside a OnClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't make a click method static is that **1)** The `android:onClick` XML action requires `public void` and **2)** The view that you are clicking belong to the *instance* of the activity, not the class.

---

You could make a static method like this.

```
public static void createDriveContents(GoogleApiClient apiClient, ResultCallback callback) {
    Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(apiClient)
        .setResultCallback(callback);
}
```

But, then you still need a reference to the `GoogleApiClient` object.
Since no client is bound to any one Activity, you could move it into a singleton in order to access one client instance from everywhere.

For example,

```
btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       MainActivity.createDriveContents(
           GoogleClientWrapper.getInstance().getClient(), // A GoogleApiClient instance
           new ResultCallback() {
               // TODO: Implement
           });
    }
});
```

If you have access to the GoogleClient in the second class, just pass in the API client object directly.

---

Or, abstracting up one level, you can instead provide a `Context`, and re-build the client.

```
public static void createDriveContents(Context context, ResultCallback callback) {

    GoogleApiClient client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context);
    // TODO: add scopes to client

    Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(apiClient)
        .setResultCallback(callback);
}
```

With this method, we assume the second class is another activity without it's own GoogleClient

```
btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       MainActivity.createDriveContents(
           SecondClass.this, // A Context instance
           new ResultCallback() {
               // TODO: Implement
           });
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't know why you are asking me that.